# dump command - does it save extended attributed, ACLs and SELinux settings on ext4 filesystems?

Tags: ext4, restore, dump

I'd like to use dump(8) for dumping an ext4 filesystem for transport to another system.  However, it is not clear from research that I have come across as to whether the dump/restore pair will transfer file extended attributes, Selinux labels, and ACLs.

Anybody know for sure?

Comment: Have you, \*gasp\*, *tried* it?

Comment: Seems to work as far as I can tell, had to harass some people to crate an environment for me for testing.  Still is this a definitive answer as I don't see much in the man pages about this.

Answer (score 0):

The ext2/3/4 dump supports extended attributes (xattr) since 2006 or earlier:

> Dump fully supports extended attributes. However, there were some issues
>   with this support in some versions of dump and/or restore, so I'd
>   suggest you upgrade to the latest version (0.4b41).

-- Stelian Pop (dump author), 2006-07-05 10:22:11, [dump users mailinglist](https://sourceforge.net/p/dump/mailman/message/6136991/)

ACLs and SElinux security contexts are stored as extended attributes.